# Stay in the same page after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the main page: `http://localhost:5111?id=12234567` (this is a `cshtml` page)

there are two links: one of them send to another controller: `src= controller2/index?id=1234567`

and the seconds send to: `controller3/index`

in the `index` of `controller2` I have another two links: one of them send to another controller: `src= controller4/index?name=abcd`, and the second send to: `controller5/preview`.

it doesn't matter which page I am found, the url is: `http://localhost:5111?id=12234567`

so when I refresh any page, I am redirected to the main page.

I want that when I refresh a page, I will stay in the same page (will the data be saved?)

any help appreviated!

Comment: Unclear what you're asking:
*Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.*

Comment: @JeffNoel No need for the bold/italics. It's clear what you're pointing out.

Comment: @Digbyswift Italics is used to show that it's actualy a quote, and not really my original sentence, but I still get your point.

Comment: It should be hitting an action method on refresh, so put some breakpoints in the controller to see what's going on...

Comment: Page inside another, we need to see some code to understand better what you mean sir.

Comment: Sounds like you're using ajax to load content.  When the content changes, the url might not.  This causes any refresh to take you to your initial view.  If that's the case, I'd suggest looking into a history plugin like sammy.js.  It took me about an hour to plug into our site and it works pretty well.

Comment: Does your URL get changed after visiting the Controller4 and Controller5.

Comment: no, it doesn't change..

@JeffCompton, I want that when refreshing a page that is built with some data, we will stay in this page (with the data that was sent) and not will be removed to the main page..

Comment: Use the url to figure out what data you need to populate the page.  For example, messages/inbox/120394 should populate the page with the inbox message that has the id 120394. You could also use a query string to figure out how you need to render the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I stay in the same page when I reload it?

Your question is irritating. There is nothing like "same page" after "refreshing". Sad but true. Either you refresh a page, which includes a whole new `HTTP-GET` of a brand new exemplar of the page -in case it was not cached; or you stay so to say on the same old one -what a waste-  the server delivered.

What you could do is: to develop a page, whose content is updated dynamically, which means, after you retrieved "fresh" content and added that to the DOM, you stay "on the same page", meaning, your browser shows the same URL as before.
But to give concrete hints, a little bit more information would be nice.

EDIT: 
Okay! The additional Information is a little bit helpful, but not quite enlightning.
As far as I can get it, you have some routing problems. To "stay on the same page" your controller has to redirect the user after a `POST` to the same URL. If you want to display the entered data, you have to use a model which contains the data entered to render the values to the page.